# Do low voltage "Nixie tubes" exist?

Tags: safety, low-voltage, nixie

I want to make a small clock using Nixie tubes (for the cool/retro/steampunk look of them), I have some basic knowledge of electronics, but I have never done anything with more than 12V DC and ~10A. I saw that Nixie tubes are usually using 3mA at 180V in order to make the Neon glow and I am concerned with the safety concerns.

Because I do not want to hurt myself with a shock of 180V caused by a mistake due to my poor experience with high voltage, **I wonder if some indicator tubes that look like Nixie ones are functioning in low voltage/current ?**

I know no Nixie tubes at low voltage can not exist because the gas needs to be excited to produce light, thus, the "look like" is very important.

Comment: Perhaps you can make some out of LED filament. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LED_filament

Comment: [This](https://hackaday.io/project/18633-lixie-an-led-alternative-to-the-nixie-tube) looks cool.

Comment: RIP Nixie, goodmorning LED.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Fortunately not.  A nixie tube isn't a visual display device, just as a steam locomotive isn't a transport vehicle and a violin isn't a musical instrument.

Comment: Use a HD LCD with a picture of a nixie tube display. Nobody will notice the difference!

Comment: Large Nixies are quite difficult to get today and expensive. I'm already having LED filaments shipped to me from China (without having to break a bulb to get them.) These are 28 LEDs of two types within a phosphor/silicon sleeve and are flexible (to an extent) and cost about 25 cents per filament. They require about 70 V and 10 mA (each filament) to operate. Lower voltage than Nixie but the overall power for a display will be higher, regardless, but also brighter, too. (LED filaments may soon be used as analog clock hands for night use, too.)

Comment: One trick I've seen is multiple layers of clear Acrylic with a digit engraved in each layer and each is separately edge illuminated with LEDs. While it doesn't really look like a Nixie, it has the same 3D look. Unfortunately, you'll probably need to find someone with a laser engraver to make the panels and make the LED assembly yourself.

Comment: @DoxyLover: Such displays were used back in the days of nixie tubes, side-lit with incandescent bulbs rather than LEDs, so that approach would still retain retro appeal.  Another approach might be to use a "projection" display [traditionally lit with incandescent bulbs, but again LEDs might work].

Comment: There used to be a "hot wire" display that could run on 12 volts.  Not exactly what you want but it still has a retro look.  A pre-led 7-segment.  Don't know if they still exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, low voltage *nixie* tubes do not exist.  But if you're after that nixie tube "look" you can buy Numitrons that work at 4.5v.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uT5W2IU7Ft0 for an example of what a Numitron looks like.

Comment: Please provide a picture, youtube links go down and people are unlikely to watch the video.

Comment: Ha!  Russian Numitrons are on Amazon.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question succinctly, no they do not exist.

Comment: A 2nd sentence explaining why might be useful...

Comment: The OP already stated why.

Answer (score -1):

Yes they do look for a tube number GE Y1938 , i own 4 , datasheet is on google

Comment: That a vacuum fluorescent display (VFD), not a Nixie tube (neon gas discharge). Completely different technology. Also, it's 7-segment, not fully-formed digits like a Nixie has.